# There was a short period of connection refused during docker swarm update

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a cluster built by docker swarm, which runs a springboot project. When I upgraded the image that it was running, and task status changed to running, LB directed me to this node, but the response was connection refused, the following is my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now I suspect that the springboot project has not fully started successfully, and the task status become running. I want to know if there is any way to make the Springboot start successfully before the task status becomes running.

Answer (score 0):

Add a healthcheck to the service.

This can be done in the Dockerfile via a

```
HEALTHCHECK ["CMD","curl http://localhost:8080"]
```

or via the stack.yml file.

For services with a healthcheck, Docker swarm does not consider the service started until the healthcheck passes and only then adds it to the load balancer.